# Sign GRUB2 bootloader to enable UEFI secure boot

Tags: grub2, uefi, secure-boot

Following preliminaries:

- Linux 4.2.3-gentoo
- GRUB2
- UEFI, Secure Boot off

Now, I want to mess with the secure boot so I'm able to turn it on. More or less following [this guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sakaki%27s_EFI_Install_Guide/Configuring_Secure_Boot), I have:

1. backed up the default keys from MS:

   ```
   #efi-readvar -v PK -o old_PK.esl
   #efi-readvar -v KEK -o old_KEK.esl
   #efi-readvar -v db -o old_db.esl
   #efi-readvar -v dbx -o old_dbx.esl
   ```
2. generated my own keys:

   ```
   #openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/CN=my platform key/" -keyout PK.key -out PK.crt -days 3650 -nodes -sha256
   #openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/CN=my key exchange key/" -keyout KEK.key -out KEK.crt -days 3650 -nodes -sha256
   #openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/CN=my kernel signing key/" -keyout db.key -out db.crt -days 3650 -nodes -sha256
   #cert-to-efi-sig-list -g "$(uuidgen)" PK.crt PK.esl
   #sign-efi-sig-list -k PK.key -c PK.crt PK PK.esl PK.auth
   ```
3. cleared the keys in BIOS so `efi-readvar` outputs no keys on reboot
4. set the backed up keys back and appended mine:

   ```
   #efi-updatevar -e -f old_KEK.esl KEK
   #efi-updatevar -e -f old_db.esl db
   #efi-updatevar -e -f old_dbx.esl dbx
   #efi-updatevar -a -c KEK.crt KEK
   #efi-updatevar -a -c db.crt db
   #efi-updatevar -f PK.auth PK
   ```
5. signed the bootloader:

   ```
   #cp /boot/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi /boot/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi.old
   #sbsign --key db.key --cert db.crt --output /boot/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi /boot/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi
   ```

The verification runs through:

```
#sbverify --cert db.crt /boot/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi
 Signature verification OK.
```

Still, when I turn secure boot on in BIOS and reboot, the usual error message is displayed and GRUB is not invoked as if it was not signed. What do I miss?

Comment: Are you using OVMF on KVM or its a baremetal setup?

Comment: Non, no vrtualization at all. Unfortunately, I moved to booting up the kernel directly from UEFI (EFI stub), so I got rid of GRUB anyway now.

Comment: Can you check your signatures with pesign? It will let you know if the keys are signed with your certificates. Moreover you should check your certificate db using certutil

Comment: You're right, there's obviously something wrong here. `pesign` gives me the error: "Could not initialize nss: The certificate/key database is in an old, unsupported format." And `certutil -L -d $efidir` outputs: "certutil: function failed: SEC_ERROR_LEGACY_DATABASE: The certificate/key database is in an old, unsupported format." I have no clue what to do now, since I try to keep the system up to date, is it an issue with my hardware?

Comment: I dont think it is a hardware issue. Can you try adding your newly generated keys in certificate database?  Following link will be helpful for this : https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:UEFI_Image_File_Sign_Tools

NOTE: I suggest to follow complete steps (starting from key generation). I have successfully used this to generate keys for myself

Comment: Above steps worked for you?

Comment: are you sure your boot entry is configured to run the right signed binary at boot? Because it is usually runs bootx64.efi. Could you verify with efibootmgr -v please?

Comment: And also, just a terminology correction (not that important), but you are using the words BIOS and UEFI as the same thing, but they are different, when you said "cleared the keys in BIOS", actually you meant "cleared the keys in UEFI". Also, you didn't turn on the secure boot on BIOS but on UEFI. UEFI is the firmware that replaced BIOS and came with your computer, even if you run UEFI in legacy mode, the firmware is still UEFI that is emulating the behavior of BIOS.